# select2 set value to selected or placeholder

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-select2

I'm using select2, to create a dropdown menu with options 1-6

```
$('#main-search-dropdown').select2({
     placeholder: "Select a number"
});
```

The thing is, I have an API that handles what's being selected and submitted, then refresh the the page data. The dropdown also reloads, but in the code, the number is still selected, though, the dropdown box text is still the placeholder, not the value that's selected.

Any idea how I get this to display the selected text instead?

Comment: Would you post an example of your problem?

Comment: There are two options in Select2 plugin `refresh` and `destroy`, you can either refresh the plugin or bind the function after destroy it after loading your items.

Answer (score 1):

Try reinitializing the drop-down

```
$('#main-search-dropdown').select2();
```

Comment: Reinitializing it didn't do anything.

Comment: try trigger change @JesperAndersen

Answer (score 0):

Try trigger change

```
$('#main-search-dropdown').val(null).trigger('change');
```

Refer the documentation of select2: 
[select2](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items)